# Use api key in HTTParty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, rest, httparty

I am trying to access a service which uses the url format. www.example.com/api/API_KEY/action

The below code is a small example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
require 'httparty'

class MyAPI
  include HTTParty
  debug_output $stdout

  base_uri "example.com/api/#{@api_key}"

  def initialize(api_key)
     @api_key = api_key
  end

  def statistics
    return self.class.get("/statistics")
  end
end
```

The server request:

```
MyAPI.new('apikey').statistics
```

comes out as

```
GET /api//statistics
```

I knew it was optimistic but I put the api_key variable in the base_uri. How do I make it so that the url uses the dynamic api_key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a reader method for @api_key.

Add the following to your class to allow the setting of @api_key after initialization.

```
attr_accessor :api_key
```

Or add to allow it to be read, but not set later.

```
attr_reader :api_key
```